# Loop through 3 maps to get the values of the same key

Tags: java

I am trying to put all values in the 3 maps `directionMap. directionMap2, directionMap3` in the JSONArray `stop`. In these maps all keys `name` (stop_name) are the the same but the values `timeEntries, timeEntries2, timeEntries3` (mon-fri, sat, son) are different so I want to put all these values in the same JSONObject `arrivals` but I facing problem to loop through all these 3 maps to get all values of the same key together?

I have tried to put the 3 for loops them in each other but it was not the right solution.

I appreciate any help.

**The result should look as this simple:**

```
[
   {
      "arrival_time": {"mon-fri": ["04:24","05:10","05:40"],
                       "sat": ["05:34","05:55","06:15"],
                       "son": ["07:00","08:00","05:40"]

                       }
      "stop_name": "garden street"
   },
   {
      "arrival_time": {"mon-fri": ["04:24","05:10","05:40"],
                       "sat": ["05:34","05:55","06:15"],
                       "son": ["07:00","08:00","05:40"]

                       }
      "stop_name": "luise street"
   }
]
```

**Code:**

```
  JSONArray stops = new JSONArray();

        for (int index = 0; index < mainList.size(); index += 3) {

            RouteCreator route_mon_fri = mainList.get(index);
            Map<String, List<String>> directionMap = route_mon_fri
                    .getDirectionMap();
            String direction = route_mon_fri.getDirection();
            String route = route_mon_fri.getRoute();

            RouteCreator route_sat = mainList.get(index + 1);
            Map<String, List<String>> directionMap2 = route_sat
                    .getDirectionMap();

            RouteCreator route_son = mainList.get(index + 2);
            Map<String, List<String>> directionMap3 = route_son
                    .getDirectionMap();

            List<String> timeEntries;
            for (Entry<String, List<String>> entry : directionMap.entrySet()) {
                String name = entry.getKey().trim();
                timeEntries = entry.getValue();

                try {
                    JSONObject stop = new JSONObject();

                    JSONObject arrivals = new JSONObject();
                    JSONArray timeArray = new JSONArray(timeEntries);
                    //JSONArray timeArray2 = new JSONArray(timeEntries2);
                    //JSONArray timeArray3 = new JSONArray(timeEntries3);
                    arrivals.put("mon-fri", timeArray);
                    //arrivals.put("sat", timeArray2);
                    //arrivals.put("son", timeArray3);

                    stop.put("arrival_time", arrivals);
                    stop.put("stop_name", name);
                    stops.put(stop);
                    System.out.println(stops.toString(3));

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
            List<String> timeEntries2;
            for (Entry<String, List<String>> entry2 : directionMap2.entrySet()) {
                timeEntries2 = entry2.getValue();
            }
            List<String> timeEntries3;
            for (Entry<String, List<String>> entry3 : directionMap3.entrySet()) {
                timeEntries3 = entry3.getValue();

            }


}
```

Comment: Am I right to say that: directionMap contains the map from stop name to the Mon-Fri arrival times, directionMap2 contains  the map from stop name to the Sat arrival times and directionMap3 contains  the map from stop name to the Sun arrival times and all of them have the same number of entries?

Comment: @TonyVu: yes you are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your portion starting from the for loop with this:

```
JSONArray root = new JSONArray();
for (Entry<String, List<String>> entry : directionMap.entrySet()) {
    JSONObject stop = new JSONObject();
    String stopName = entry.getKey();
    stop.put("stop_name", stopName);

    JSONObject arrivalTime = new JSONObject();
    JSONArray monFriArrivalTime = new JSONArray();
    JSONArray satArrivalTime = new JSONArray();
    JSONArray sunFriArrivalTime = new JSONArray();
    for (String str: entry.getValue()) {
        monFriArrivalTime.add(str);
     }
    for (String str: directionMap2.get(stopName)) {
        satArrivalTime.add(str);
    }
    for (String str: directionMap3.get(stopName)) {
        sunFriArrivalTime.add(str);
    }
    arrivalTime.put("mon-fri", monFriArrivalTime);
    arrivalTime.put("sat", satArrivalTime);
    arrivalTime.put("sun", sunFriArrivalTime);
    stop.put("arrival_time", arrivalTime);          
    root.add(e);
}
System.out.println(root);
```